# AST-based search for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, search, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a plug-in for Eclipse that lets you search based on the Java AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of your project files?  The "Java Search" feature doesn't seem to cover cases like:

"Get me all the fields declared as type 'X' in all classes"

I can imagine many more possibilities that would open up with an AST-based search, but I don't even know if such a plug-in would have practical performance.

**Update**: As pointed out by Kevin below, the Java Search feature does cover the use case I mentioned.  I'm still curious though about whether or not someone has written a plug-in that allows any arbitrary kind of AST search, ex. "Get all string concatenations" (InfixExpression with + operator and StringLiteral operand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get me all the fields declared as type
>   'X' in all classes

I don't know what else you had in mind but I believe you can accomplish this specific search by doing the following:

- Opening up type X (Ctrl-Shift-T)
- Highlight the class name
- Ctrl-H to search
- Search for Type / Match Locations -> Field Types

Comment: That seems to just return the declaration of the type itself.

Comment: Sorry.  I edited the entry to use the Match Locations filter instead of Declarations.

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you.  I had never tried the Match Locations option before.  That at least covers the use case I mentioned.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it covers most cases where I might have otherwise wanted an AST-based search.

Answer (score 2):

There are several Eclipse plug-ins that provide object-oriented query languages and aim to answer such queries. Some of them:

- [Browse-by-Query](http://browsebyquery.sourceforge.net/)
- [SEA-QL](http://www.seambase.com/products.htm)
- [Semmle code](http://semmle.com)

Outside Eclipse there is [JArchitect](http://www.javadepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) Code Query Language

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but nWire for Java can give you a lot of information which is derived from the AST. It also has a full text search for searching any type, method, field, etc. Once you find what you're looking for, a click will show you all the associations of that component.

Check out the demo [here](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java).